# Game center authenticate on simulator, but nor actual device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am attempting to add game center to my application and all goes well for the simulator, but when I run it on the device, it always says game is not recognized by game center.  I have attempted to log out of game center than back in hoping it places me in "sand box" but it apparently does not.

If it matters, my devices are running iOS 5 beta 7.  Any ideas why okay on simulator and not device?  Thanks in advance.

Geo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it must have been something to do with running beta and something got "hung", because I restarted the iPad and all is well.  Although I did have to make sure I was logged out of Game Center on the device and then log in via my app.

Geo...